# Inject Silex $app to custom Controller class

Tags: dependencies, silex

What I have:

```
# index.php
$app = new Silex\Application();

... (loading routes file by YamlFileLoader) ...

$app['routes']->addCollection($loader->load('routes.yml'));
$app->run();
```

Routing:

```
# routes.yml
home:
    pattern: /
    defaults: { _controller: 'Controllers\DefaultController::indexAction' }
```

How can I get access to the $app instance inside controllers?
It's simple:

```
# controllers/DefaultController.php
class DefaultController
{
    public function indexAction(Request $request, Application $app)
    {
        // this is the place!
        return $app['twig']->render('index.twig');
    }
}
```

Ok, it's fine, but there are several reasons why this method is unacceptable for me. And I want to use the classic way:

```
# controllers/DefaultController.php
class DefaultController
{
    public function indexAction()
    {
        return $this->twig->render('index.twig');
    }
}
```

To provide that, I want to use the parent base class:

```
# controllers/BaseController.php
class BaseController
{
    protected $twig;

    public function __construct(Application $app)
    {
        $this->twig = $app['twig'];
    }
}
```

And as you might expect:

```
# controllers/DefaultController.php
class DefaultController extends BaseController
...
```

**So, which way is better for inject silex $app to Base Controller?**

Comment: Note that you can define your controllers as services: http://silex.sensiolabs.org/doc/providers/service_controller.html

Answer (score 1):

I use to do the same as you want to do with your `BaseController`.

In a Controller class, define the `connect` method like this:

```
class MyController implements ControllerProviderInterface                                                                                                                                                                                         
{                                                                                                                                                                                                                                             
    protected $app;                                                                                                                                                                                                                           

    public function connect(Application $app)                                                                                                                                                                                                 
    {                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         
        $this->app = $app;                                                                                                                                                                                                                    
        $controller_collection = $app['controllers_factory'];                                                                                                                                                                                 

        $controller_collection->get('/', array($this, 'searchForm'))->bind('user_search_form');

        // DECLARE ALL YOUR ROUTES HERE
    }

    public function searchForm()
    {
        return $this->app['twig']->render("search_form", array ... )
    }
}
```

It works pretty well. I would also not advise you to use YML for routing unless you cache the PHP somewhere or you want performance issues.

Comment: @CSchulz - if this way doesnt work because it now offers ServiceControllerServiceProvider but how do you hook it into a silex system that uses YAML like him?